# port number not change for docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, portforwarding

I have specified port-mapping in docker-compose, but it is still not working, i still have to access site using the port no specified in expose

below is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '2'

networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: nat

services:

    website:
        build:
            context: '.'
            dockerfile: "./iis.dockerfile"
        ports:
            - 3000:8081
```

and the corrosponding `dockerfile`

```
FROM microsoft/iis

RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET"]
RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45"]

ADD www/ c:\\webapp

EXPOSE 8081

RUN powershell New-Website -Name 'web-app' -Port 8081 -PhysicalPath 'c:\webapp' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'
```

I have to access app using: `http://192.168.105.33:8081/`, if I do it using port 3000 it does not work.

Is there anything missing in my above configuration?? OS: `windows server 2016`, using windows containers with `hyper-v` and `docker-compose up -d` to get containers up and running...

docker-compose inspect gives me below output

```
 "Ports": {
     "8081/tcp": [
         {
             "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
             "HostPort": "3000"
         }
     ]
 },
```

`docker ps` gives me below output

```
  eb7aa1e74b7f        website_website     "C:\\ServiceMonitor..."   14 minutes ago      Up 14 minutes       0.0.0.0:3000->
```

8081/tcp   website_website_1

`dokcer-compose ps` gives me below output

```
  Name                    Command             State           Ports
  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  website_website_1   C:\ServiceMonitor.exe w3svc   Up      0.0.0.0:3000->8081/tcp
```

So I should be able to access it on host using port 3000.

Comment: is 192.168.105.33 IP of your host or the docker container?

Comment: its the ip of docker container, i am not hosting site on my machine... i m hosting it in docker container

Comment: `ports` maps the port from container to your host, so in all likelihood you can just go to `http://localhost:3000` and find your page there

Comment: Have you checked your networks by using `docker network ls` You explicitly specified nat network. Did you created a custom one or using default? And what is output of `docker ps`?

Comment: This may be related. https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/21558

Comment: @user3012759 great to know this... but i tried localhost with both ports, but its not working on any port.. interesting

Comment: @icewind thats definitely close, but that issue is resolved. may be I need to open issue there... btw, nat is the default network available on server 2016.. i did not created a new network

Comment: @entre the github isse may be related... seems that loopback does not work on windows (so no localhost) so you may want to try to reach your container from outside of your server <ip-of-your-server>:3000 just make sure 3000 is open on the firewall...

Comment: @entre The issue is closed because they hoped this will be fixed in TP5 but recent comments show us this wasn't fixed. 
On win/mac docker is running inside a vm and creating a new network. So you have to make sure NAT is working properly from outside. Connect to your docker host and try to open it locally(from host machine) at least with curl.
Find docker machine ip `docker-machine ip name`. You can find the name using `docker info`

Comment: Also you need to correctly forwarded desired ports in your *host* network. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/management/container_networking

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you're launching your container with `docker-compose run`? There is a difference in port mapping between `docker-compose run` and `docker-compose up [-d] [service]` In this case the port configuration will be [ignored by design](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/run/)
You can use `--service-ports` flag or manually expose them using `-p` flag

Comment: i am using `docker-compose up -d` to run the container network

Comment: @entre have you checked your container with `docker inspect`? And maybe looked in `docker-compose logs` or `docker logs`?