# Changing 8081 port of Mongo-express

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose, port, docker-container

I'm working on a new stack, with mongo express on it and port 8081 is already allocated on my computer by McAfee and I can't disable it,

So I changed it on `docker-compose.yml` to 443, I tried others too

```
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 443:443
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: tutu
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: toto
```

But when I `docker-compose up -d` ports of mongo express is not completly set to 443 and I got on logs :

```
mongo-express_1  | Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081
```

I work on Docker for Windows (10) behind a proxy, and the stack is running well on another computer on the same network, and it's working too at home

I tried to restart Docker, to --force-recreate, delete container and recreate

I used `docker inspect ID` too and I got this

```
"NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "3fa04e921ee43231f30169efecda8356fa90e4d0cfff54c3b2151e649f2397d8",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "443/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                        "HostPort": "443"
                    }
                ],
                "8081/tcp": null
            },
```

I'm pretty sure the stack is not running cause of this but I can't find a solution

I checked these topic too :

[How to run MongoDB and Mongo-express with docker-compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901561/how-to-run-mongodb-and-mongo-express-with-docker-compose)

[port number not change for docker-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41140554/port-number-not-change-for-docker-compose)

Maybe I can provide more information I'm not a docker specialist

Answer (score 1):

By default, the SSL connection uses TCP port 443.
In your case, the server uses HTTP on port 8081 (inside the container).

If you still want to use the 443 port to connect over HTTP you need to fix docker-compose as follows:

```
mango-express:
    image: mango-express
    ports:
      - 443:8081
```

The first argument is the host settings, the second argument is the settings inside the container. You can also specify the ip address, for example `127.0.0.1:443:8081`

Port mapping is incompatible with `network_mode: host`

[docker-compose ports](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)

Comment: Hello, I tried this too, but not working too sadly, can I try this with another port ? I don't get what port can I use maybe

Comment: I checked this compose file:  
`version: '2'

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    ports:
      - 443:8081
    links:
      - mongo`

it's perfectly working on my machine. Check you McAfee and be sure that needed port is open.

Comment: I tried with ```3009:8081``` 3009 is opened, but not working and still got ```mongo-express_1  | Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081```

Comment: Run `docker ps` command. If you see in "PORTS" column value like this 0.0.0.0:3009->8081/tcp is all right. 
"mongo-express_1 | Mongo Express server listening at http://0.0.0.0:8081" is in container address

Comment: Yeah I got ```0.0.0.0:3009->8081/tcp``` so I got another problem I guess